# sorting in md-table angular material2 not working

Tags: angular, observable, angular-material2

Here is the component.ts

```
export class RoleListComponent {
    displayedColumns = ['roleAvatar', 'roleName']; // list of columns to show on UI
    dataSource: RoleDataSource;

    @ViewChild(MdSort) sort: MdSort;

    constructor(private roleService: RoleService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new RoleDataSource(this.roleService, this.sort);
    }
}

export class RoleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    roles: Observable<Role[]>;
    constructor(private roleService: RoleService, private _sort: MdSort) {
        super();
    }
    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<Role[]> {

        this.roles = this.roleService.getRoles();
        const displayDataChanges = [
            this.roles,
            this._sort.mdSortChange,
        ];
        return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map(() => {
            return this.getSortedData();
      });

    }
    disconnect() { }

    compare(a: string, b: string, isAsc: boolean) {
        return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
    }
    /** Returns a sorted copy of the database data. */
    getSortedData(): Role[] {
        let sortedData:Role[];
        this.roles.subscribe(data => {
            debugger
            if (!this._sort.active || this._sort.direction == '') { return data; }

            sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
                let isAsc = this._sort.direction == 'asc';
                switch (this._sort.active) {
                    case 'roleAvatar': return this.compare(a.name[0], b.name[0], isAsc);
                    case 'roleName': return this.compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
                }
            });
            console.log(sortedData)
            return sortedData;
        });
        return sortedData;
    }
}
```

There is a `roleService.getRoles()` method of `roleService` that return the `Observable` of type `Role[]`. I have merged the observable of mdSort and the this.roles observable and returned the `getSortedData()`.

Now in the getSortedData() method, I have subscribed the this.roles observable to get the array of roles and sorted that array and returned from inside the subscribe. There is the return of getSortedData() itself and on call of this method it returns method's return statement rather than subscribe's return, so sorted data is undefined and no records on UI. I am confused how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning an `Observable<Role[]>` from `getSortedData()` and using `switchMap` in `connect()`.

```
export class RoleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  roles: Observable<Role[]>;

  constructor(private roleService: RoleService, private _sort: MdSort) {
      super();
  }

  /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
  connect(): Observable<Role[]> {

      this.roles = this.roleService.getRoles();

      const displayDataChanges = [
          this.roles,
          this._sort.mdSortChange,
      ];

      return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges)
        .switchMap(() => this.getSortedData());
    });

  }
  disconnect() { }

  compare(a: string, b: string, isAsc: boolean) {
      return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
  }

  /** Returns a sorted copy of the database data. */
  getSortedData(): Observable<Role[]> {

    return this.roles.map(data => {
      if (!this._sort.active || this._sort.direction == '') { return data; }

      return data.sort((a, b) => {
        let isAsc = this._sort.direction == 'asc';
        switch (this._sort.active) {
          case 'roleAvatar': return this.compare(a.name[0], b.name[0], isAsc);
          case 'roleName': return this.compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        }
      });

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: now every time sort data on UI it calls the getRoles again and again that internally hit http request to get data. Any solution to this?

Comment: Use a BehaviorSubject to emit results from the api. Call the api, emit the result into a BehaviorSubject, and then don't emit into the BehaviorSubject again until you have new data. Then `getSortedData` can access the BehaviorSubject stream each time to manipulate the "cached" results